# 12v relay to open and an close switch without sending power to switch

Tags: electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, electrical

Sorry if this is elementary but here's what I need.

I'm trying to power a relay via 12v DC (vehicle) to open a closed switch while the 12v power is sent to the relay. Essentially, when the blinkers blink, it will open the switch each time they blink. The switch must remain closed when the blinkers are not switched on (blinking).

In addition to that, I need to open the resting closed circuit without feeding power to it. I've attached an image as an example.

[image]

I realize the above example may not even exist, but I hope it helps you understand what we're trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Comment: Check out a relay that is Normally Closed (NC) - it opens when powered, some relays (changover) do both...

Comment: Thanks!
I bought and have these: https://www.amazon.com/Pack-EPAuto-Relay-Harness-Bosch/dp/B072QXDZRD
I'm able to create the circuit where it's normally open, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it sit at closed.

I have a resistor between the 30 (blue) and 87 (yellow) and when 12v is introduced into the 86 (red) while properly grounded, the 10k resistance is shown on my multi meter. I need it to show 10k (completed circuit) without the 12v, and open it when 12v is active.. Did I purchased the wrong relays, or am I missing something?

Comment: Terminals 30 and 87a provide the normally closed contacts which you want. When you apply power to the coil (86 and 85) then the closed contacts become 30 and 87.

Comment: Make sure you are using a double-throw relay, such as the one lexguru suggested.  Just to be clear:  you want your orange-side switch to close the moment you remove your external 12VDC?  If not, you'll need to investigate latching switches.